# Compile error in c files

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

I have a c file inside "examples" folder inside ArtoolKIt that I want to compile in Ubuntu.
Artoolkit works perfectly, but how can I compile this c file from terminal?
I try ./helloWorld but it gives me this error:

> No such file or directory

Is there any specific way to compile Artoolkit programs cause I don't see it in its docuemntation.

Answer (score 0):

Use either gcc or clang to compile .c files:

```
gcc -o hello ./examples/filename.c
```

the parameter following the -o flag names the file that will be produced by the operation, a parameter without any flag named the source input file.

Comment: @EldaBacka: "it doesn't work" may be an accurate description, but it does not give us anything to work with. ... Did you think of pressing 'Enter' after typing that in? And so on.

Comment: It says fatal error! My root is like this ArtoolKit/Examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.c and I go to the helloWorld folder by using terminal and do this: gcc -o helloWorld

Comment: @EldaBacka: that is not the line that SoronelHaetir suggested. It is missing the .c file name.

Comment: gcc -o helloWorld.c you mean? Cause this gives the same error. Can you write the whole line for helloWorld.c file?

Comment: @usr2564301  now I posted my answer to this question! I apprecieate your help. And I edited my question! Can you please upvote my question if you like the answer since I have been banned for 6 months? Thnaks!

Answer (score -2):

So, the problem that I had was with my directories! For this wo work you should have inside teh folder Examples of ArtoolKit the thiungs: a folder with data, your c file to be compiled and teh makefile in case you have it so youy can compile with $make command.
Now It works for me!